# How to navigate from one view controller to another view controller on button click?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, navigation, uibutton

I am new to iOS Application development, please help me how can I go from one `view controller` to another `view controller` on button click?

Comment: On the IB builder, drag controll drag the button to the next view. (you CANT do this to go back, you have to use dismissmodalviewcontroller method)

Answer (score 11):

Follow the below step,let the button selector is

`[button addTarget:select action:@selector(buttonClick) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];`
and implement the selector as

```
-(void)buttonClick{
UIViewController *controler = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controler animated:YES];}
```

and also make sure viewController has NavigationController embedded within it and replace UIViewController with the Controller you wish to push.

Answer (score 8):

Use this code in your `Objective-C` function for navigation -

```
DashboardViewController *dvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DashboardView"];
[dvc setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];
[self presentViewController:dvc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Code is indented by 4 spaces or 1 tab. You can also select the code and press Ctrl+K.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
nextViewController *obj =[[nextViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"nextViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];
[obj release];
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use any of approach -

> 1. pushViewController: animated: - To Push the view on navigation stack
> 2. presentModalViewController:nc animated: - To present the view modally.

Answer (score 4):

```
YourSecondViewcontroller *temp = [[YourSecondViewcontroller alloc]initWithNibName:@"YourSecondViewcontroller" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:temp animated:YES];
```

//or

```
[self presentModalViewController:temp animated:YES];
```

[`Visit this reference for tutorial and working demo code`](http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/08/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-transitioning-between-views/)

Hope, this will help you..enjoy

Answer (score 2):

> //SAViewController will be your destiation view
>
> // import SAViewController.h file in your current view

```
SAViewController *admin = [[SAViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SAViewController" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:admin animated:YES];
[admin release];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
- (IBAction)btnJoin:(id)sender {

   SecondViewController *ViewController2 = [self.storyboardinstantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController: ViewController2 animated:YES];

}
```